# How to save a rendered image that I have added a vignette to in Compositing?

Tags: compositing-nodes

I have a rendered image in compositing with a node set up to add a vignette. It all looks good in the compositing window but I cannot find a method to save this new image.

Answer (score 15):

Actually there is a way to save the composited image *without* re-rendering:

1. select the viewer node
2. in the N panel (properties region) under "Node" there is a "Save This Image" button.

Answer (score 5):

There are two ways to save it.

The first way is to predefine the output in the properties panel under render>output.  You can set a destination and file type there.  Once you click render the image will automatically save there.

The second way is to render the image with the vignette, and then select Image>Save Image As  at the bottom of the render panel.

Comment: or connecting the last node to a file output node:) I'm not so sure about your first method.

Comment: Images are only saved in the output folder if you rendered by pressing 'Animation'.

Comment: I tried the first way already but get the original render without the vignette...so I guess I have to try the second way....when I try to Render from  the compositing window I do not get the vignette....

Comment: Thank you guys..root, Ray and CyberBurst...I had failed to use a file output node as suggested by root.

Comment: Hovering over the render window, press F3

Comment: I believe using the output, whether in the UI or as a node, will only work if you hit animation button

Comment: @Gavia you have to render again to have your image saved through the file output node(it will use the path in your render settings). if you switch to the UV image editor you can select the viewer node and save it like Georges suggested. or you can render a 1 frame animation if you set the start and end frame to the same value..

Comment: Got it! and many thanks for the invaluable help.

Answer (score 5):

Go to the uv image editor and select the viewer node in the image list. Then you can save it.

Comment: How does this add anything? [This answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/68314/2217) already has this solution.

Comment: Actually, this is the only simple answer that works and to the point.

Comment: There seem to be no "Save This Image" in blender 2.93 anymore. The UV editor is one (or only) of remaining options.